# i can't test my Counter Solang program "Error: unknown signer: "

Tags: solang

Guys i have problem testing Solang, if u can help me with this should be great! =)

Github Repo:

https://github.com/sistemaseltigre/ClasesTwitch/tree/anchor/counter

Versions tools:

solana-cli 1.16.4 (src:4ce8fe76; feat:2891131721, client:SolanaLabs)

anchor-cli 0.28.0

cargo 1.70.0 (ec8a8a0ca 2023-04-25)

Error:

```
 counter-solang
Your data account address JATAzNH3DCqizZiSBuxN3HYpaNbmcqmWBNT2kJBwHGBF
Error: unknown signer: JATAzNH3DCqizZiSBuxN3HYpaNbmcqmWBNT2kJBwHGBF
    at Transaction._addSignature (/home/chuo/Documents/QuicknodeGuide/github/ClasesTwitch/counter-solang/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/legacy.ts:732:13)
    at forEach (/home/chuo/Documents/QuicknodeGuide/github/ClasesTwitch/counter-solang/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/legacy.ts:708:12)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Transaction._partialSign (/home/chuo/Documents/QuicknodeGuide/github/ClasesTwitch/counter-solang/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/legacy.ts:706:13)
    at Transaction.partialSign (/home/chuo/Documents/QuicknodeGuide/github/ClasesTwitch/counter-solang/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/legacy.ts:698:10)
    at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/home/chuo/Documents/QuicknodeGuide/github/ClasesTwitch/counter-solang/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:152:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/home/chuo/Documents/QuicknodeGuide/github/ClasesTwitch/counter-solang/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
Your transaction signature undefined
    1) Is initialized!
    2) Increment


  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1) counter-solang
       Is initialized!:
     
  Error: 
      at AnchorProvider.simulate (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:323:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at simulate (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/simulate.ts:37:16)
      at MethodsBuilder.view [as _viewFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/views.ts:24:30)

  2) counter-solang
       Increment:
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x2
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5922:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5881:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:370:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:160:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

Comment: Ran into the same error. It seems to be causes by the `modifier` in the contract and this may be an issue with Solang (since using a modifier in a separate function shouldn't be causing the constructor to throw an error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is an issue with Solang. The modifier was changing the data account's signer flag to false, so the account you passed was not identifier as a signer, leading to the "Unknown signer" error.

We've merged a [fix](https://github.com/hyperledger/solang/pull/1459) and it will be out for the July release.

Comment: ok thank you very much I will wait for the release and try again, the project is very good

Comment: @JesusSilva There was a release on August 24th. Have you had the change to try it again?